# Set bootstrap panel width to text width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to HTML/Boostrap so maybe this is fairly easy - How do you set the panel width of [a bootstrap panel](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels) to the length of it's text?

If it isn't possible with a panel, is there a similar bootstrap component that anyone knows of that I can use? The closest thing I've seen are [labels](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#labels), but they are too small.

Comment: Please post a working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: @vanburen I think this is unnecessary. This question refers to the general properties of a standard component.

Answer (score 10):

## Make the Bootstrap panel more modest

Let's use the [Basic panel example](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-basic). We have to set the `display` property as `inline-block` for two classes: `.panel` and `.panel-body`.

We can do it by using of special CSS-class or id. Check the result:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

#modest,
#modest .panel-body,
.panel-modest,
.panel-modest .panel-body {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    Basic panel example
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default panel-modest">
  <div class="panel-body">
    Modest panel uses class
  </div>
</div>

<div id="modest" class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    Modest panel uses id
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to set the display property as inline-block in the HTML for a specific panel insiead of the CSS? From my understanding, your CSS would affect ALL of my panels right? I only want that property applied to specific panels, not all.