# bootstrap responsive panels that do not exceed page width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I correctly format a bootstrap panel to not exceed the width of its parent div when the panel contents expand. I also want the panel to be responsive in that it shrinks and expands based on the browser window but I do not want overflow at the bottom of the page.

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
   <div class="panel-heading"></div>
     <div class="panel-body text-info">
        //content that may expand or shrink
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set bootstrap panel width to text width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667224/set-bootstrap-panel-width-to-text-width)

Comment: I would request a code sample that illustrates the problem. By default, `panel` takes up 100% of its parent container's width.  The only scenario in which I could get text to exceed the width is if there are no spaces or where word wrapping was disabled (ex: setting `white-space: nowrap`).

Comment: I have a kendo grid inside the panel that allows for the columns to be resized. When you drag the column and the panel grows beyond the current width of the page, it creates an overflow scroll at the bottom. I would like the panel itself to scroll instead

Comment: Based on your response I would say that your code example is woefully insufficient.  You're talking about an entire other framework interacting with this component, and a level of content that isn't represented in your example.